# How to give each store object it's own arrayList of stock?

Tags: java, arraylist

Finding this one tough, basically I have three classes: Store class, Stock class and then the class for the GUI. When a store is created, I want it to have it's very own arraryList so that I can add multiple stock objects to it. (done through the GUI).

I've tried to only include the basic code that is needed, (have deleted the getter methods, setter methods, default constructors compareTo etc.)

Here's some of the code of the classes (that could very well be wrong)

```
public class Store  {

private int id;
private String name;
private String location;


private ArrayList <Stock> stockItems = new ArrayList<Stock> ();


public Store(int idIn, String nameIn, String locationIn) {
    id = idIn;
    name = nameIn;
    location = locationIn;
    ArrayList <Stock> stockItems = new ArrayList<Stock> ();
}





//to add stock items to a store?
public void addStockItem(Stock s) {
    stockItems.add(s);

}
```

}

Stock class

```
public class Stock {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int units; 



    public Stock(int idIn, String nameIn, double priceIn, int unitsIn) {
        id = idIn;
        name = nameIn;
        price = priceIn;
        units = unitsIn;
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track? In the GUI, what would I call to add a stock item in to a specific store from the GUI?

Thanks.

Comment: This line in the constructor `ArrayList <Stock> stockItems = new ArrayList<Stock> ();` should be `stockItems = new ArrayList<Stock> ();` since you've already defined the variable.

Comment: Oops. I actually changed that, forgot to change it when I put it up here. Thanks though!

Comment: You're welcome, this probably fixes your whole problem ;)

Comment: Still a little confused what to do in the GUI unfortunately. As in, how would I make a certain stock go in to a certain store?

Comment: You can provide the user with a list of stores to choose from. On submit you can retreive the corresponding store and call `addStockItem()`.

Comment: Thanks. Just updated the original question, would that be right do you think?

Comment: I think you'd better create another question for this, for the sake of keeping Stackoverflow clean and readable. Also, this way you can accept an answer to the original question. Tip, reference the new question here, I'd be happy to help you out.

Comment: Great thanks, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the constructor of `Store`, you have

```
ArrayList <Stock> stockItems = ...
```

That is actually creating a local variable `stockItems`, instead of changing the field. To make it work use just

```
stockItems = ...
```