# Adding information to arrayList of an object

Tags: java, arraylist

Basically I have three classes: Store class, Stock class and then the class for the GUI. When a store is created, I want it to have it's very own arraryList so that I can add multiple stock objects to it. (done through the GUI).

I've tried to only include the basic code that is needed, (have deleted the getter methods, setter methods, default constructors compareTo etc.)

Here's some of the code of the classes:

Store

```
public class Store  {

private int id;
private String name;
private String location;


private ArrayList <Stock> stockItems = new ArrayList<Stock> ();


public Store(int idIn, String nameIn, String locationIn) {
    id = idIn;
    name = nameIn;
    location = locationIn;
    stockItems = new ArrayList<Stock> ();
}





//to add stock items to a store?
public void addStockItem(Stock s) {
    stockItems.add(s);

}


}
```

Stock

```
public class Stock {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int units; 



    public Stock(int idIn, String nameIn, double priceIn, int unitsIn) {
        id = idIn;
        name = nameIn;
        price = priceIn;
        units = unitsIn;
    }

}
```

GUI: (just the code that's related to my question)

```
    int indexStore = lst_Store.getSelectedIndex(); //store that the user selects from list
    int indexStock = lst_Stock.getSelectedIndex(); //stock item selected by user

    //get the specific stock details
    Stock s = stocks.get(indexStock);

    Store z = new Store(); //so i can call method below

    z.addStockItem(s);
```

It's the GUI code that's really messing me up, basically I want to add the stock selected to the store that was selected. When this is done, how would you go about accessing the information in the arrayList of a particular store too?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305941/how-to-give-each-store-object-its-own-arraylist-of-stock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305941/how-to-give-each-store-object-its-own-arraylist-of-stock)

Comment: Got asked to create a new one because in that one I wasn't too specific about the GUI.

Comment: @C101der that's why StackOverflow is all about editing

Comment: No it isn't. This is a totally different question while the previous question has already been answered. Numerous edits for an exact case would have no future value for people with similar issues.

Comment: @C101der: In the last sample, there a row `Stock s = stocks.get(indexStock);`. Where is the variable `stocks` coming from? I'm asking this since `Store` has `stocks` though you already have `stocks` and you want to set one of these into the `Store`.

Comment: Oh sorry. stocks is my arrayList of stock. I also have an arraylist of stores called stores if that makes sense? In the GUI the user adds the stock and then it gets put in to stocks first, then later on they can add it to a store.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is I would add each store reference to a list of its own.

```
ArrayList<Store> storeList = new ArrayList<Store>();
//This next line will add it at the location of the store ID so you can reference it by that unique number later on
storeList.add(z.getStoreID, z);
```

Now when you need to reference that store later on you can say

```
Store s = new Store();
s = storeList.get(storeIDYoureInterestedIn)
```

I'm still pretty new overall so this is probably not the best solution but it is how I would approach it.

Comment: Actually this is a pretty good approach. Though you shouldn't set `Store s` with `Store s = new Store();`. Just do `Store s = storeList...` right away.

Comment: Thanks. Still a bit confused but I'll give it a shot.